# How to I append a suffix to an animated counter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having difficulty adding a static suffix to the end of these animated counters. I'd like to add a "+" sign to some of them, doesn't need to be animated.

I tried creating a suffix class but I can't get it to append directly to the end value, it just keeps appearing below the numbers. I am a complete beginner so if there's an obvious solution I apologize! I've searched the forums but the approaches don't seem similar to mine.

```js
let valueDisplays = document.querySelectorAll(".num");
let interval = 4000;

valueDisplays.forEach((valueDisplay) => {
  let startValue = 0;
  let endValue = parseInt(valueDisplay.getAttribute("data-val"));
  let duration = Math.floor(interval / endValue);
  let counter = setInterval(function() {
    startValue += 1;
    valueDisplay.textContent = startValue;
    if (startValue == endValue) {
      clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, duration);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 28vmin;
  height: 28vmin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

i {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3.8em;
  text-align: center;
}

span.num {
  color: #000000;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 3em;
}

span.text {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  pad: 0.7em 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 85vw;
  }
  .container {
    height: 26vmin;
    width: 26vmin;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 90vw;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 30px;
  }
  .container {
    width: calc(50% - 40px);
    height: 30vmin;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .wrapper {
    gap: 15px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vmin;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-face-laugh"></i>
    <span class="num" data-val="8">0</span>
    <span class="text">Apples</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-users"></i>
    <span class="num" data-val="40000">0</span>
    <span class="text">Oranges</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-down"></i>
    <span class="num" data-val="2.3">0</span>
    <span class="text">Lemons</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-podcast"></i>
    <span class="num" data-val="900">0</span>
    <span class="text">Pears</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it enough to do `valueDisplay.textContent = startValue + '+';` in the script? Or adding another span with a '+' to the markup?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you can use the [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-element to inject the `+`.

However, I had to remove the `grid` display for the `.num` elements, as that didn't align the added `+` nicely.

See the CSS block in this snippet.

```js
let valueDisplays = document.querySelectorAll(".num");
let interval = 4000;

valueDisplays.forEach((valueDisplay) => {
  let startValue = 0;
  let endValue = parseInt(valueDisplay.getAttribute("data-val"));
  let duration = Math.floor(interval / endValue);
  let counter = setInterval(function() {
    startValue += 1;
    valueDisplay.textContent = startValue;
    if (startValue == endValue) {
      clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, duration);
});
```

```css
.num:after {
  content: '+';
}

span.num {
  text-align: center;
}

/* ^ That's all there is to it. */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 28vmin;
  height: 28vmin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

i {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3.8em;
  text-align: center;
}

span.num {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 3em;
}

span.text {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  pad: 0.7em 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 85vw;
  }
  .container {
    height: 26vmin;
    width: 26vmin;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 90vw;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 30px;
  }
  .container {
    width: calc(50% - 40px);
    height: 30vmin;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .wrapper {
    gap: 15px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vmin;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-face-laugh"></i>
    <span class="num" data-val="8">0</span>
    <span class="text">Apples</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-users"></i>
    <span class="num" data-val="40000">0</span>
    <span class="text">Oranges</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-down"></i>
    <span class="num" data-val="2.3">0</span>
    <span class="text">Lemons</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-podcast"></i>
    <span class="num" data-val="900">0</span>
    <span class="text">Pears</span>
  </div>
</div>
```